# How to allow connection for edb database in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

By mistake we have executed disallow connections for all databases after that we are not able to connect any of the database, see below for reference:
Executed Query:

```
edb=# update pg_database set datallowconn=false;
```

```
[root@keng02-dev01-ins01-udm12-dbs-1510678526-01 ~]# psql -U tkcsowner
Password for user tkcsowner:
psql.bin: FATAL:  database "edb" is not currently accepting connections
```

Is there a way we can allow connections to edb or enterpriseDB without using PSQL? Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

With PostgreSQL in general (not EDB specifically) you would do:

- stop the PostgreSQL server
- start `postgres`  in a shell in [single user mode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-postgres.html#APP-POSTGRES-SINGLE-USER).
- `UPDATE pg_database SET datallowconn=true WHERE ...` [to undo the error]. Be aware that `template0` should normally be left with `datallowconn=false`.
- Type Ctrl+D to quit the single user mode.
- start PostgreSQL normally.